# Does 3D Secure provide a significant security benefit that justifies a worse UX?

Tags: credit-card

We have a website that uses Stripe for charging customers. We are selling a physical product that has zero resale value and a service that is completed 30 days after the customer receives the physical product. In other words, the customer gains nothing from using a stolen credit card if it's discovered quickly. The average purchase is 1000 USD.

We are not using 3D Secure because it feels like better UX not to go through an additional step of verifying their details which creates a risk that the user will not complete a transaction. As soon as they click Pay Now, they are charged.

We are also in a country with a low risk of fraud.

Does using 3D Secure provide any significant security benefit that justifies the worsened UX of having an additional redirect to the bank's page and having to enter your details there?

Comment: Security benefit to whom?  To the merchant (you), to the cardholder, or to the issuing bank?

Comment: to me the merchant @Bobson